# Sanitization of global Attributes in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

As Salesforce recommend **Sanitization of global Attributes**, So we were looking for some Library which can sanitize the html for us. Is there any Library in Lightning or another JS library which we can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use secure filters third party library to sanitize

https://github.com/salesforce/secure-filters

This is recommended in the lightning security guidelines documented in the blog

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Security